# Data Mapping between two different Database Schemas

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, data-migration, data-mapping

I have to design a system with an sql database whose work is to get data from different databases which may be in another database such as mysql or oracle etc. Then the system will map the attributes of that database with my database schema and store them..
Example reference link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa728893(v=vs.71).aspx
Since I am new, I can't attach images which is why I am providing links.

All my searches end up with getting the mapping tools but what actually I want is how to create that tool myself. 
I am not a professional but a little push will be enough for me and highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you checked out Entity Framework?  You can have different providers for the various databases.  And then use something like AutoMapper to map between the models.

Comment: You went to wrong side.. i am going to create a cloud based service that will get data from different systems , then map according to own database schema and store it.. To elaborate, i take example of hospital management system. my service will collect data from databases of different hospitals created by different vendors using different databases, then map that data with my own db attributes. i hope u can understand now what i want

Comment: This can be done easily by using Sql Server Integration Services to map and store the data for you. If you really need to create this on your own I would simply map the tables within xml files. These file you can be generated by using a `.tt` file (TextTemplates) so you don't have to do it manually.

Comment: @MihailStancescu Can you please elaborate a little more... I think this is what i am searching for.. An example would be great for me if possible and please reply as an answer so i can mark it right..

Comment: @dustmouse Are you serious? You would suggest a data integration with EF? JESUUUUUUUS !!!!

Comment: @Atiqurrehman - so how do you get the data from different systems?  Through a REST api?  JSON?  Does it even matter what database system it comes out of, or are you purely interested in the mapping component?

Comment: @dustmouse yes it does matter because my attribute names and datatypes may b different from the source database attribute and datatype respectively !

Comment: @dustmouse if you can't be constructive or say something usefull, better stay quiet. otherwise, .... grow up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This, as I said in the comment, sounds to me a job for an Integration Services package.

If you would like to use Microsoft SQL Server Integration Services you should first have [Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt204009.aspx) installed on your development machine.

Afterwards you start by creating a new Integration Service project inside Visual Studio. Then you can add an ODBC Connection Manager to manage your different databases input of data. After that you can add a different transformation container objects in your package to transform the data as you need it. At the end you need to specify the output of all those elements into your database where you want to store the information that you collect from other sources.

You can also create a different package for every source database you have so that the tasks can be separated. Unfortunately a complete tutorial is very long for me to post here but you can check out the tutorial on [Microsoft web site](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms169917.aspx). An other example [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/635956/How-to-export-data-from-database-tables-to-an-XML).

As as warning you should be **really careful** with data types because if you don't match/convert them correctly the package will fail with not so obvious errors.

If you choose the `.tt`(T4 Template) solution in which you create the application then you should start by connecting to the sources database and loop through tables definitions to get the columns and then store them as a xml file. The matching you will have to do it inside the text template file so that you have the matching already done when the table is read from the data source.

[Here](http://www.programering.com/a/MjN0YjNwATM.html) is an example that should get you started. Note that in the example the output file will be a .cs file not .xml but you can configure that very easily with this T4 directive `<#@ output extension=".xml" #>`.

Comment: SSIS is a solid tool, but heavily dependant on meta data and takes a long time to master. pentaho or talend are more suited for someone who heard about ETL for the first time

Answer (score 0):

Please, ignore for this task, any form of programming, Do not do it. Especially ignore Entity framework.

I would recommend you to take one of the many ETL tools out there, and design the work with it. I can recommend you [Talend](https://www.talend.com/products/talend-open-studio) . It is very easy to learn and in time, even a developer starts to work with it.
The best part about it that it can connect to webservices, enterprise solutions and probably any imaginable Database out there.

What you do is to design Jobs that run on its own in parallel, and then you export the jobs as standalone JARs. A chroneJob, or a scheduled service completes the process to have it executed periodically

Comment: what if i don't want to use existing tools ?

Comment: you will have a really hard time. change requests will come and ETL maintainance is easier in a tool than in code. plus its faster